# Morphia update method is ambiguous

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, morphia

I use Morphia to make update mongoDB data.

I have create somthing like this:

```
public  UpdateResults<? extends BaseEntity> update(Query<? extends BaseEntity> query,UpdateOperations updateOp) throws WriteConcernException{
            return datastore.update(query, updateOp);
      }
```

When i run my application on eclipse i haven't any problem.

So when i run maven build i get this error:

```
reference to update is ambiguous, both method <T>update(T,org.mongodb.morphia.query.UpdateOperations<T>) in org.mongodb.morphia.Datastore and method <T>update(org.mongodb.morphia.query.Query<T>,org.mongodb.morphia.query.UpdateOperations<T>) in org.mongodb.morphia.Datastore match
```

I effectively use the following method

```
<T>update(org.mongodb.morphia.query.Query<T>,org.mongodb.morphia.query.UpdateOperations<T>)
```

Why eclipse use correct method and maven not ? I can't understand.

How can i fix it for maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary solution you might use `datastore.update(query, updateOp, false)` instead of `datastore.update(query, updateOp)`. It will pass **createIfMissing** parameter as **false** and it is already default behavior; so, it will not cause any problem.